# Prove $1<\frac1{e^2(e-1)}\int_e^{e^2}\frac{x}{\ln x}dx<e/2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, contest-math

Prove the following inequalities:

a) $1.43 < \int_0^1e^{x^2}dx < \frac{1+e}2$

b) $2e <\int_0^1 e^{x^2}dx+\int_0^1e^{2-x^2}dx<1+e^2$

c) $1<\frac1{e^2(e-1)}\int_e^{e^2}\frac{x}{\ln x}dx<e/2$

Source: http://www.sms.edu.pk/downloads/prceedingsfordae1/1_intinequal.pdf

---

We know $\sqrt{\pi}/2=\int_0^\infty e^{x^2}dx>\int_0^1 e^{x^2}dx$, and according to Google calculator (https://www.google.com/search?q=sqrt(pi)%2F2&oq=sqrt(pi)%2F2&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.3176j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8 ) $\sqrt{\pi}/2\approx 0.88622692545$, while $\frac{1+e}2>1$. But $1.43$ doesn't look right. Maybe there's a typo in the pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start. For $(a)$, we have, for $0\leq x \leq 1$

$$ 1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!} \leq e^{x^2} \leq e^x\implies 1.43 \leq \int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}dx \leq {e-1}< \frac{e+1}{2} .$$

**Note:** We used the Taylor series of $e^{x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

for c use mean value theorem for integral calculus.Ie. take $f(x)=\frac{x}{ln x}$ in the interval $[e,e^2]$.
since maximum value of the function in the given interval is $e$ and $\frac{e^2}{2}$ at $x=e$    and  $x=e^2$  using maxima minima test.Hence applying meanvalue theorem we get
$$ e<\frac{\int_e^{e^2} \frac{x}{ln x}}{e^2-e}<\frac{e^2}{2}$$
rearranging we get $$1<\frac{\int_e^{e^2} \frac{x}{ln x}}{e^2(e-1)}<\frac{e}{2}$$